# How to discard the first spike after auto-correlation and handle sloping auto-correlation output

Tags: autocorrelation, signal-processing, fourier-transform

Disclaimer: I am not very mathematically inclined and am mostly looking to be pointed in the right direction.

I have various signals that I am putting through an auto-correlation function that uses two DFTs. The output of auto-correlation of two of those signals is shown below.

[image: Signal1]

[image: Signal2]

I am looking to discard the initial spike in the case of Signal1, and I am looking for a way to handle the slope of Signal 2. Both of these are necessary since I am using a simple max function to determine the highest spike, but this doesn't work with the inclusion of the smaller lags and downward sloping correlations.

-Since I am using two DFTs, is there some way for me to use the output from the first to trim the output of the auto-correlation?

-Is there some way for me to trim some frequencies to avoid downward sloping outputs?

-Is there something better than the max function that will solve both of these problems?

I'd greatly appreciate any information anyone has on solving these problems.

Comment: Please label your axes correctly --- at the moment it is not clear whether these are in the time domain or the frequency domain.

Comment: @Ben The graphs are generated using the output of the auto-correlation function, which is showing different lags. The images have been updated.

Comment: The y-axis cannot be autocorrelations, since autocorrelations are ... *correlations* --- which are between -1 and 1; your y-axis exceeds 1

Comment: @Glen_b I just don't have the output normalized. Since I'm looking for the max anyway, there isn't a point for me to squash it between -1 and 1. But you're right, I should've mentioned.

Comment: They're autocovariances? Or by "not normalized" did you mean they're not divided by something related to sample size (typically n-1)?

Comment: @Glen_b To be honest, I'm not sure. To get it between 0 and 1, it's `(x[i] / n - meanSquared) / stdDevSquared` for each element in x. I'm not sure conceptually what that does, I just know I don't need to do it if I'm just finding the max.

Comment: It sounds like maybe its a raw sum of products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thank you to Glen_b whose comments helped me see what needed to be fixed with my approach.

A major issue with my data was that I wasn't centering it before putting it through my auto-correlation function. This (I assume) is why the output of my auto-correlation function was always positive, and never negative as Glen_b suggested it should be. While it is still not between 1 and -1, it is much closer to a real correlation now. After fixing this, I discovered that my "normalization" function (not actually normalization, I just am still not sure exactly what it does) makes a significant difference to the output of the graph.

After applying this shift to all points after correlation on centered data, my two graphs now look like shown bellow. (note: the x axis has been divided by 3, so a peak at 1500 on the originals would coincide with the peak at 500 on the new)[image: Output1.2]
[image]

With this, my two problems are solved. I can trim the first spike by only looking at values that exist beyond the first negative correlation, and the output is now even with the x axis.

Edit: After testing on the rest of my data, it seems that in about 20% of my cases the outputs do not go negative after the first spike. Regardless, this has still been a major improvement.

Comment: Thank you again to @Glen_b. I wouldn't have figured this out if I hadn't realized my auto-correlation function should output negatives as well as positives.